# Is it recomended to enable Remote Blob Storage in Production without Third Party?

Tags: remote-blob-storage, rbs, shredded-storage

We have to implement the RBS in SharePoint 2013 and we don't want to use any third party. Can we use RBS without third party in a Production environment? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. 
I still have query for our case, we are having a scenario where we will produce 4 TB documents in one year and I heard we have a limitation of content database can't increase beyond 200 GB while RBS. So including RBS and Content database can we be able to accommodate 4 TB with one RBS enabled content database per year ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to implement RBS without a 3rd party solution. The provider from Microsoft is called [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx) and gets shipped with SQL-Server.

Please consider the following before implementing any solution to externalize your BLOBs:

- Read the following excellent Technet-Article: [Deciding to use RBS in
  SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628583.aspx)
- Every RBS-Solution (FILESTREAM or 3rd party) requires you to get a
  [SQL-Server Enterprise license](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748649.aspx#Section2)
- If you use FILESTREAM, you can store BLOBs only to a disk that
  appears as local hard disk in diskmanagement of Windows (hard disk,
  iSCSI disk or FibreChannel disk). If you want to store your BLOBs
  elsewhere (FileShare, NFS, ...) you have to buy a 3rd party tool like
  AvePoint StorageManager or Metalogix StoragePoint. ([Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638709.aspx))
- RBS adds a lot of complexity to your environment. Especially
  backup&restore must be planned accordingly as a Database-Backup will
  no longer cover your BLOBs. Your administrators should fully
  understand what happens when using RBS to still be able to
  troubleshoot your farm if something goes wrong. Or get a experienced
  consultant.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. 
I still have query for our case, we are having a scenario where we will produce 4 TB documents in one year and I heard we have a limitation of content database can't increase beyond 200 GB while RBS. So including RBS and Content database can we be able to accommodate 4 TB with one RBS enabled content database per year ?.

Comment: Please read the section "Content Database limits" in the following article carefully and follow all steps described there: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc262787.aspx#ContentDB. You should strongly consider to split your content across several SiteCollections and then split them to several smaller Content Databases