# Confused in Shredding and RBS

Tags: rbs, shredded-storage

I have read several article about shredding and RBS like [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2015/02/19/sharepoint-2013-shredded-storage-vs-rbs.aspx), [2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/11/20/3532049.aspx),...

in my (probably wrong) understanding there is conflict between RBS and shredding. for example if i set RBS limitation for 1MB, files never go to RBS. because there are shredded in 64 KB and so there are smaller than 1 MB, so the only way to use RBS is changing FileWriteChunkSize property that affect storage growth like example in 1. as a result i must choose between using RBS or shredding. it would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already found out all relevant parameters:

- if you use the Microsoft FILESTREAM-Provider to configure RBS, your
  only option is the filesize to determine if a file should be moved
  out of the ContentDatabase
- SharePoint 2013 has the new feature
  ShreddedStorage. Default is to create 64KB chunks of every file
  ("Shred")
- So if you want RBS to externalize files larger than 1MB,
  you have to configure the FileWriteChunkSize to a value larger than
  that.

Your Options:

- Stay at the FILESTREAM provider and modify FileWriteChunkSize to your
  needs.
- Buy a 3rd party RBS-Provider. Those tools are able to schedule
  jobs which can move content out by a lot of other parameters than
  only the file size. You can also choose the filesize and you are not
  affected by the FileWriteChunkSize problem.
- [Rethink if you really need RBS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151652/is-it-recomended-to-enable-remote-blob-storage-in-production-without-third-party/151692#151692). Unfortunately you did not specify any infos about your planned environment.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation,as i got because of complexity of deployment and non-integrity Backup process of 3rd party RBS-provider we should discard using that and handle our multimedia files in other way than SharePoint.